# POST REST API using ApacheHttpClient

Tags: java, json, rest, post, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using Java for Posting  json payload to Canvas Rest Api using ApacheHttpClient

I am getting error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 422.I have referred the following link on stack overflow [POST request to REST API with JSON object as payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889013/post-request-to-rest-api-with-json-object-as-payload)

My code is:

```
     try{

         httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
            httpPost = new HttpPost("https://canvas.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/10300000000000133/assignments/10300000000000860");

            List<NameValuePair> headers = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); //ArrayList to store header parameters
            List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); //ArrayList to store URL parameters
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("query","{\"id\":10300000000000860,\"description\":\"\",\"due_at\":\"2017-04-19T03:59:59Z\",\"unlock_at\":\"2016-04-13T04:00:00Z\",\"lock_at\":\"2016-04-22T03:59:00Z\",\"points_possible\":3,\"grading_type\":\"points\",\"assignment_group_id\":10300000000000297,\"grading_standard_id\":null,\"created_at\":\"2014-06-21T13:50:05Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2016-05-05T23:53:35Z\",\"peer_reviews\":false,\"automatic_peer_reviews\":false,\"position\":1,\"grade_group_students_individually\":null,\"anonymous_peer_reviews\":null,\"group_category_id\":null,\"post_to_sis\":null,\"moderated_grading\":null,\"course_id\":10300000000000133,\"name\":\"Units and Dimensions new\",\"submission_types\":[\"online_quiz\"],\"has_submitted_submissions\":false,\"muted\":false,\"html_url\":\"https://canvas.instructure.com/courses/10300000000000133/assignments/1030~860\",\"has_overrides\":false,\"needs_grading_count\":0,\"integration_id\":null,\"integration_data\":{},\"quiz_id\":10300000000000539,\"anonymous_submissions\":false,\"published\":true,\"unpublishable\":true,\"only_visible_to_overrides\":false,\"locked_for_user\":false,\"submissions_download_url\":\"https://canvas.instructure.com/courses/1030~133/quizzes/1030~539/submissions?zip=1\"}"));
            headers.add(new BasicNameValuePair("app-token", "1030~SAD..."));
            headers.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"));
            headers.add(new BasicNameValuePair("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"));

            for (NameValuePair h : headers)
            {
                httpPost.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
            }

            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (response.getEntity().getContent())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

The app token seems to be working .How do I correct this error,Do i need to pass some server certificares

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not doing anything with the `urlParameters` object.  I find it unlikely that the API is expecting that JSON object as a URL parameter, and instead should probably be sent with the body of the request.  I could be wrong, just pointing out another potential problem with this code.

Based on the [response code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2), it looks like the query object you are POSTing contains a logical error.

Comment: I learned that JSON isn't intended to be passed as a query argument .How can I pass JSON in a POST request, where it can be properly parsed.

Comment: You can find an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188041/write-in-body-request-with-httpclient).